# Do we need to reinstall vite+react for every project?

Tags: reactjs, npm, web, installation, mern

React installation was giving me several difficulties, and I want to start a new project with it. Do I really need to reinstall React then?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your question needs improvement.

Comment: Short answer: React is a JavaScript library that must be installed separately for each application. It's not software that resides on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can install vite cli and use it very very faster than create-react-app

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).